# VueJS set value to a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am getting confused on the warning showed by VueJS, that

[Vue warn]: *Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "moduleSpecificProps"*

This code is not a working one;
Sorry kind of lazy.
The point is I have a child module, which will accept a property(moduleSpecificProps). So if the parent pass it child will use the value(tableData: computed property), otherwise it will use the default value.

1. But my problem if i want to change the value of computed property inside the child component, how can i do that?
2. Should I keep another data field tableDataCurrentValue and update it and derive(computed property) value from tableDataCurrentValue data field ?

**I am having a thought like this way**

1. Child component will have a two data field 'default_table_data' and 'tableDataHolder'.
2. And will watch the change on 'moduleSpecificProps' when the change happens i update 'tableDataHolder'
3. And the computed property 'tableData' will return(get) the data from 'tableDataHolder' if not found use 'default_table_data'
4. On assigning values to computed property 'tableData'(child component trying to update the value) it will update 'tableDataHolder' This seems work, but not sure the using watch is good, it seems like am always end on watch.

// Child component

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
    {
        props: {
            moduleSpecificProps: {
                type: Object,
                required: false
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                default_table_data: {
                    name: 'User Data',
                    columns: [{'name': 'User id'}, {'name': 'Name'}],
                    data: []
                }
            }
     },
     computed: {
        tableData: {
            get: function() {
                var tableData_temp = this.default_table_data
                tableData_temp['name'] = this.moduleSpecificProps['tableData']['name'] || this.default_table_data['name']
                tableData_temp['columns'] = this.moduleSpecificProps['tableData']['columns'] || this.default_table_data['columns']
                tableData_temp['data'] = this.moduleSpecificProps['tableData']['data'] || this.default_table_data['data']
                return tableData_temp
            },
            set: function(tableData) {
                var tableDataOld = this.tableData
                tableDataOld['name'] = tableData['name'] || tableDataOld['name']
                tableDataOld['columns'] = tableData['columns'] || tableDataOld['columns']
                tableDataOld['data'] = tableData['data'] || tableDataOld['data']
                this.moduleSpecificProps['tableData'] = tableDataOld
            }
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And the parent script can define an instance of child like so:

```
childConfig = {
    name: 'Student Mark Data',
    columns: [{'name': 'Student Name'}, {'name': 'Mark'}],
    data: [] 
}
<template>
    <child :moduleSpecificProps="childConfig"></child>
</template>
```

Comment: This line `this.moduleSpecificProps['tableData'] = tableDataOld` is modifying a prop and causing the warning. You should instead $emit the new value and let the parent decide what to do with it.

Comment: The issue is with the `this.moduleSpecificProps['tableData'] = tableDataOld` line, are you trying to extract the data from the child?

Comment: I understand the issue is because, i trying to update the properties from child component.
The child component have the default value, if parent not passed any property(moduleSpecificProps) i need to get the value from the default value from child component.
And also the child should be able to update the value.

Comment: I am having a thought like this way

1. Child component will have a two data field 'default_table_data'  and 'tableDataHolder'.

2. And will watch the change on 'moduleSpecificProps' when the change happens i update 'tableDataHolder'

3. And the computed property 'tableData' will return(get) the data from 'tableDataHolder' if not found use 'default_table_data'

4. On assigning values to computed property 'tableData'(child component trying to update the value) it will update 'tableDataHolder'

This seems work, but not sure the using watch is good, it seems like am always end on watch.